# How can I create a new WebLogic managed server and add it to the cluster "dynamically"?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I want to be able to "spin up" additional WebLogic 11g managed servers in a cluster to add additional horizontal instances.

The use case is that I start with a WebLogic cluster that has X instances and I want to add an additional instance dynamically i.e. using a script and using a live system (without any downtime).

What can I use (e.g. WLST?) to create the additional managed server, configure it e.g. add it to the domain? Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an [example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13715/config_wls.htm#i1027812).
You can do a svr.setCluster and svr.setMachine

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with WLST:

Create:

```
connect('username','password')
edit()
startEdit()
cmo.createServer('managed1')
cd('Servers/managed1')
```

Add server to cluster (after `cd` to server added above)

```
cmo.setListenPort(ListenPort)
cmo.setCluster("MyCluster")
cmo.setMachine(Machinename)
```

Reaching/creating a cluster in WLST works in a similar way:

```
cd('/')
cmo.createCluster('MyCluster')
cd('/Clusters/MyCluster')
cmo.setClusterAddress('myhost:port,myhost2:port')
cmo.setClusterMessagingMode('unicast')
```